# Is there any events for the completion of creating configurable product and its variants?

Tags: magento2

Currently I'm using the `magento_catalog_api_data_productinterface_save_after` event to do something every time a product is created. But I noticed that for configurable products, the event is emitted more than one time because Magento is saving the child products first and then the parent product.

Is there any event for when the whole of configurable product is created?